# How to convert an indexed string value to an integer?

Tags: c#

I have a binary value stored as a string, such as:

```
string binaryValue = "1000";
```

I am trying to access index `[0]` and store it into another variable as an integer. I have tried:

```
int myVar = Int16.Parse(binaryValue[0]);
```

The error I get is:

> Cannot convert from "char" to "string".

Expected:

```
myVar = 1
```

Comment: `binaryValue[0]` is a `char` and `Int16.Parse` takes a `string`.  Just call `ToString` to make it work.

Comment: You can use `int myVar =  binaryValue[0] - 48;` but IMHO it is not your real question about your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string binaryValue = "1000";
    int myVar = Int16.Parse(binaryValue[0].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(myVar);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```